Image animation: moving picturebox in VB.NET
In a project, I am trying to create a slideshow on part of a form, animating a picturebox and sliding it from right to left, and this is working fine as long as I use only one image.
If I loop within, say, 3 images, the animation invariably displays only the last image!
I am using a picturebox (ImageSlider) and a timer (TmrMove).
Here's what I tried:
In the start slideshow button:
For Each s As String In sFiles
   Call MoveImage(s)
Next

The MoveImage method:
Private Sub MoveImage(sImage As String)
   drawingImage = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(sImage)), True, False)
   ......
   ImageSlider.Image = drawingImage
   TmrMove.Interval = 2000
   TmrMove.Start()
End Sub

And in the TmrMove_Tick event:
For x = Width To LeftBorder Step -5
   ImageSlider.Left = x
   ImageSlider.Top = TopBorder
   ImageSlider.Refresh()
Next
TmrMove.Stop()

Since I'm not good at graphics and images, could anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong and what? I suspect it has to do with waiting for completion of first sliding before continuing but can't figure out which part of my timing process is wrong.
Thx

Are you using the Image Slider from DevExpress? The link provides an example. Basically, you must load all the images before starting the animation.

No...Just trying to create mine to get a bit more used to graphics.

Since you do not show us the code of your slider, it is hard to tell you what you are doing wrong.

There's not much more code than this dealing really with the images, but I guess I'm on my way to resolve it thanks to your comment about loading all images first. Loading images in a list and moving the list into the timer tick event seems to be doing it. Refining.....

Yes, because if you want to slide from one image to another, then you need at least two images at the same time.

Thx so much! This makes sense but it's something I did not know, nor think of. Solved!

As indicated by Olivier, loading images in a list and loading images from the list in the timer tick event did the trick.
Tick event now looks like:
ImageSlider.Width = MyImageList(imgNum).Width
ImageSlider.Height = MyImageList(imgNum).Height
ImageSlider.Left = Width - ImageSlider.Width
ImageSlider.Top = TopBorder
ImageSlider.Height = LeftBorder
drawingImage = ScaleImage(MyImageList(imgNum), ImageSlider.Height, ImageSlider.Width)
ImageSlider.Image = drawingImage
For x = Width To PicImage.Left Step -5
   ImageSlider.Left = x
   ImageSlider.Top = TopBorder
   ImageSlider.Refresh()
Next
imgNum += 1
If imgNum = sFiles.Count Then
   TmrMove.Stop()
   Call StopSlideShow()
End If

May not be optimal, but works.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
